# Getting observations until and including first different value (groups with "no switch" are allowed)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a slightly convoluted way to slice a data frame by group from the first row (it always starts with the same value) till (and including) the first different value.

I though about using `slice(1:min(which == new.value))`, but there are groups where this switch does not happen - and this is what causes me headache. I could split the data into those groups where there is a switch and not and do the calculation on only those with a switch - but I would love to know if there are somewhat more elegant options out there. I am open for any package out there.

```r
library(dplyr)

mydf <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 4), value = c(1,2,2,2, 1, 1,1,1,1,1,2,2))
```

The following does not work, because there are groups without "switch"

```r
mydf %>% group_by(group) %>% slice(1: min(which(value == 2)))
#> Warning in min(which(value == 2)): no non-missing arguments to min; returning
#> Inf
#> Error in 1:min(which(value == 2)): result would be too long a vector
```

Doing the slice operation on only the groups with a switch and binding with the "no-switchers" works:

```r
mydf_grouped <- mydf %>% group_by(group) 

mydf_grouped %>% 
  filter(any(value == 2)) %>% 
  slice(1: min(which(value == 2))) %>% 
  bind_rows(filter(mydf_grouped, !any(value ==2)))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>   group value
#>   <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1
#> 2 a         2
#> 3 c         1
#> 4 c         1
#> 5 c         2
#> 6 b         1
#> 7 b         1
#> 8 b         1
#> 9 b         1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want all rows having a value of 1 as well as the row with the first 2 in each group:

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(group)  %>%
  filter(value == 1 | cumsum(value == 2) == 1) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: That's also pretty nice :)

Answer (score 2):

Here, one option is to pass the `if/else` condition

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    slice(if(!2  %in% value) row_number() else seq_len(match(2, value)) )
```

---

Or more compactly, change the `nomatch` in `match` to `n()`

```
mydf %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   slice(seq_len(match(2, value, nomatch = n())))
# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   group [3]
#  group value
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 a         1
#2 a         2
#3 b         1
#4 b         1
#5 b         1
#6 b         1
#7 c         1
#8 c         1
#9 c         2
```

Comment: Thanks ! I never stop learning from you. Using match is great.

Comment: I'll accept @G.grothendieck's solution because I find it very intuitive. But I find the combined use of seq_len(match) extremely clever and I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid` to create an index of change in `value`, `shift` it by 1 position and select all the rows till 1st change.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(mydf)
mydf[, .SD[shift(rleid(value), fill = 1) == 1], group]

#   group value
#1:     a     1
#2:     a     2
#3:     b     1
#4:     b     1
#5:     b     1
#6:     b     1
#7:     c     1
#8:     c     1
#9:     c     2
```

The same logic in `dplyr` can be implemented by

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(lag(cumsum(value != lag(value, default = 1)), default = 0) == 0)
```